# Why the smaller image's margin is changing relative to the larger mountain image instead of container div?

Tags: css-position

The cloud looks like it's inside the mountain image's box/outline. I thought the margin should be affected relative to either parent div container or viewport. I am new to CSS and don't understand why this is happening ?

Taken screenshot with pesticide activated for the outlines
[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #E4F9F5;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.cloud2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="top-container">
    <img class="cloud1" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>This is jungle</p>
    <img class="cloud2" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
    <img class="mountain" src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `position: absolute` (and `fixed`) you *always* want to provide one or more positioning constraints (i.e. [`top`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp), [`left`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp), [`bottom`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp), [`right`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_right.asp)) so that css knows how to position the element relative to the *"nearest positioned ancestor"*.

By positioning an element absolutely, you are telling css that you want to position this element such that it takes up no space on the [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) with regard to the [flow layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout). Without providing any positioning constraint css only knows the element to which it should position.

You may assume the default is just to place the element in the top left (i.e. `top: 0, left: 0`) but that's not the case. The absolute element will just be thrown where it would have been positioned as a static element but without taking up any of the block/inline space. So this is why the order of the element relative to its siblings is important **when** no positioning constraints are used. By the way I have NEVER used this in my career, I've always used positioning constraints to be explicit! See demo below.

[image: sibling impact demo]

So short answer is just use positioning constraints and you're good.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #E4F9F5;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.cloud2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-container">
    <img src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/538-5386297_cloud-outline-png-clipart-transparent-background-gray-clouds.png" alt="cloud-img" width="20%">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>This is jungle</p>
    <img class="cloud2" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/538-5386297_cloud-outline-png-clipart-transparent-background-gray-clouds.png" alt="cloud-img" width="20%">
    <img class="mountain" src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/111-1118124_cartoon-clip-art-transprent-png-free-download-mountain.png" alt="mountain-img" width="80%">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

There are many [gotchas](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/top-right-bottom-left/#gotchas) with `position: absolute` so be aware.

> ### Aside
>
> CSS takes time to know and understand. There are rules to guide you
> but a lot of the learning process is trial and error and on top of that the rules are somewhat different between browsers too. I've found many
> solutions to extreme edge cases that I have since forgotten, the trick
> is to remember just enough to find the solution again. Over time it
> will become second nature. Also using the dev tools `elements->styles`
> panel to quickly experiment can help you find a solution or learn
> about all the properties and their values.